# Error installing ODS Framework in Virtuoso open source

Tags: ubuntu, frameworks, virtuoso

I have installed `develop/6` branch from Virtuoso on my Ubuntu machine. Everything works fine apparently, but when I try to install ODS Framework appears the following message error:

```
00000 Errors detected
00000 Installation of "ODS Framework" was unsuccessful.
      The installation of this VAD package has failed.
      Please delete the transaction file /usr/local/virtuoso-opensource/var/lib/virtuoso/db//usr/local/virtuoso-opensource/var/lib/virtuoso/db/virtuoso.trx
      and then restart your database server.
      Note: Your database will be in its pre VAD installation state after you restart.
00000 FATAL
```

I have tried to use an older version of ODS Framework package (1.87.26), but the error persists.

This is my log:

```
09:04:32 PL LOG: SQ200: Table referenced in contains does not have a text index while executing the following statement: --no_c_escapes- create procedure scot_tags_insert (in inst_id int, in post_iri any, in tags var 
09:04:32 PL LOG: SQ200: Table referenced in contains does not have a text index while executing the following statement: --no_c_escapes- create procedure scot_tags_delete (in inst_id int, in post_iri any, in tags var 
09:04:32 PL LOG: SQ200: No table RDF_WEBID_ACL_GROUPS while executing the following statement: --no_c_escapes- create procedure WEBID_CHECK_ACL (in ag any, in gr any, in cert any, in realm any, out env any) { decla 
09:04:32 PL LOG: Errors where detected during installation of "ODS Framework". 
09:04:32 PL LOG: The installation of this VAD package has failed. 
09:04:32 PL LOG: Please delete the transaction file 
09:04:32 PL LOG: /usr/local/virtuoso-opensource/var/lib/virtuoso/db//usr/local/virtuoso-opensource/var/lib/virtuoso/db/virtuoso.trx 
09:04:32 PL LOG: and then restart your database server. 
09:04:32 PL LOG: Note: Your database will be in its pre VAD installation 
09:04:32 PL LOG: state after you restart. 
09:04:35 Server shutdown complete
```

---

This is my log:

```
09:04:32 PL LOG: SQ200: Table referenced in contains does not have a text index
while executing the following statement:
--no_c_escapes-
create procedure scot_tags_insert (in inst_id int, in post_iri any, in tags var
09:04:32 PL LOG: SQ200: Table referenced in contains does not have a text index
while executing the following statement:
--no_c_escapes-
create procedure scot_tags_delete (in inst_id int, in post_iri any, in tags var
09:04:32 PL LOG: SQ200: No table RDF_WEBID_ACL_GROUPS
while executing the following statement:
--no_c_escapes-
create procedure WEBID_CHECK_ACL (in ag any, in gr any, in cert any, in realm any, out env any)
{
  decla
09:04:32 PL LOG: Errors where detected during installation of "ODS Framework".
09:04:32 PL LOG: The installation of this VAD package has failed.
09:04:32 PL LOG: Please delete the transaction file
09:04:32 PL LOG: /usr/local/virtuoso-opensource/var/lib/virtuoso/db//usr/local/virtuoso-opensource/var/lib/virtuoso/db/virtuoso.trx
09:04:32 PL LOG: and then restart your database server.
09:04:32 PL LOG: Note: Your database will be in its pre VAD installation
09:04:32 PL LOG: state after you restart.
09:04:35 Server shutdown complete
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check your virtuoso.log file.

Just above the lines you show here, is another couple of lines that hold the clue to why the package could not be installed.

If you cut/paste them in an email to me, i will help you understand why the package could not be installed.

Of course you could try to load all the SQL scripts and other parts by hand, but the reason of the VAD is to make this simpler.

Comment: I wasn't using virtuoso-t command, so the solution is doing call from which is in the bin/virtuoso-t to start the program after the installation.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been fixed in the internal archives. An update to the external git open source archives is being prepared and should be available in the next few weeks ...